# How to start the mail app from titanium

Tags: iphone, email, titanium, appcelerator

How do you start the Mail app from a Titanium app?

I am looking for the equivalent of an HTML mailto: link where I can specify the email and maybe the subject from with in a windowView.

I am not using a webView.

Will

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var emailDialog = Titanium.UI.createEmailDialog();
emailDialog.subject = "Sending email from Titanium";
emailDialog.toRecipients = ['name@gmail.com'];
emailDialog.messageBody = 'Appcelerator Titanium - Testing sending email';

emailDialog.open();
```

But remember that you cannot test this send email feature from iPhone Simulator (because iPhone simulator lacks of setting email account). Try to check in real phone.

Comment: you forgot the semi-colon on the first line.

Comment: yes :p . I forgot this, but luckily you found and reminded me. Thanks.

Comment: looks like a typo you've copied from the Titanium docs http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.EmailDialog ;)

Comment: @Dallas Clark I'm not sure. It was 2 years ago, and now Titanium API has changed a lot.